# Amazon s3 file upload confusion

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3 to upload files from my server to amazon's one.
Everything is working perfectly but I'm going crazy because of an issue:

I am uploading several files and folders (mostly images, js and css files). The files get uploaded nicely however I have one particular css file (jquery-mobile-1.0.1.css) that gets uploaded however when an html relies on that file, the css is not loaded, until I go and manually upload that one file again and make it public.
I literally tried everything (changed file name, location, encoding) but nothing seems to be working. Does anyone have an idea what can cause the problem?
The files are uploaded dynamically, so the way that the particular css file gets uploaded does not differ from other css files.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: the file actually now called jqm.css

Comment: yeah I see it - ok upload manually

Comment: Have a look.... There shouldn't be any images now, so its ok. But you can click on ask and go to other pages...You see the dirrefence

Comment: can you put it back the other way now?

Comment: Mind blowing! Do you think it's because of the way the file is uploaded? but the css file is loaded. I can see in google chrome!

Comment: No clue, I looked at it for 10 minutes, couldn't see anything wrong.  The CSS in both cases is identical - I used WinDiff to check.  As a General Rule of Thumb.  Always load CSS before Javascript files.  A lot of Javascript/JQuery code depends on styles/positions/sizes etc - I've seen very inconsistent results putting CSS after Javascript - Whether that is your problem or not, I don't know.  If It fixes it let me know and I'll write an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but that is the first css I load. All the js files come after that. I cannot think anything else then the way I upload the file from my server. If you write an answer I'll accept it for your efforts.

Comment: What is the Content-Type Set to for that file In S3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mime type (HTTP content type header) on the files you uploaded is incorrect. S3 does not always set them correctly.  Both JS files and CSS files are set to text/html - should be `text/css` and `text/javascript`.

You need to set them appropriately on the upload API call. Some upload libraries will do this for you, yours clearly isn't.

http://orensol.com/2009/07/14/google-chrome-2-css-content-type-and-amazon-s3/